# how to handle failure response in retrofit 2.0

Tags: java, retrofit, retrofit2

I'm working on retrofit 2.0 i have set everything right i'm getting the correct token but at the end message goes to failure. i have also made one response class which i'm getting through postman. i have also appended a bearer token there.i have tried everything but non of them work. Main activity 
` private void hitApi(String token) {

```
    startLoading();
    RetrofitRequest.retrofitGetRequest().listAuth( AppContants.getBearerToken(token) , "0")
            .enqueue(new Callback<ListCallback>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse (Call<ListCallback> call, Response<ListCallback> response) {
                    stopLoading();

                    if (response.code() == 200) {
                        Log.e("tag",response.toString());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else if (response.code() == 401) {
                        showErrorDialog("Authentication Failed");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure (Call<ListCallback> call, Throwable t) {
                    stopLoading();
                    showToast(getString(R.string.error_message));
                }
            });
}
```

---

Api class

---

```
@GET("devices/list")
Call<ListCallback> listAuth( @Header("Authorization") String authToken, 
@Query("pageNumber")String pageNumber);

 Response class`@SerializedName("id")
 @Expose
  private int id;

@SerializedName("machineId")
@Expose
private String machineId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;

@SerializedName("locationCountry")
@Expose
private String locationCountry;


@SerializedName("manufacturer")
@Expose
private String manufacturer;

@SerializedName("productType")
@Expose
private String productType;

@SerializedName("currentStatus")
@Expose
private String currentStatus;

@SerializedName("completedPercentages")
@Expose
private int completedPercentages;


public int getId () {
    return id;
}

public String getMachineId () {
    return machineId;
    }

public String getName () {
    return name;
   }

public String getLocationCountry() {
    return locationCountry;
}
public String getProductType () {
    return productType;
}

public String getCurrentStatus () {
    return currentStatus;
    }
public int getCompletedPercentages () {
    return completedPercentages;
      }

}
```

Comment: what's the issue? and print your exception in `onFailure()` an post it here